# Loop to replace c:\, d:\ ... z:\ with \\servername\c$\

Tags: powershell, shared-directory, access-rights

I'm actually trying to build some code to identify rights on shared folders in every single server I've got in my enterprise.

For now, I've already listed every single server and exported it in a .txt file, did a loop on this .txt to export in an other .txt file all shared folders.

All this is working fine but the path is like : `c:\...\...\folder$`.
To be able to use this I need to do a loop to replace `c:\` `d:\` etc. with `\\servername\c$\`.

I've tried using `[system.io.file]::ReadAllText` and `WriteAllText`, it's working fine for one letter but didn't find a way to do a loop on it.

I've tried

```
get-content ... -replace "c:\","\\$ServerName\c$\" ` -replace "d:\" ...
```

but got an error about regular expression not valid, so trying with `[regex]::Escape` but didn't work as expected neither...

Powershell

```
$contenu = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllText("$path\$SharedFolders.txt").Replace("C:\","\\$SharedFolders\c$\")
[System.IO.File]::WriteAllText("$path\$SharedFolders.txt", $contenu)
```

Powershell

```
(Get-Content "$path\$SharedFolders.txt") | foreach {
    $_ -replace "C:\","\\$SharedFolders\C$\" `
 -replace "D:\","\\$SharedFolders\D$\" `
[...] | Set-Content "$path\$sharedfolders.txt"}
```

And i'd like to have something like that :

Powershell

```
('a'..'z').ForEach({ (Get-Content "$path\$SharedFolders.txt" -Raw).replace("$_`:\","\\$SharedFolders\$_$") })
```

But I'm too newbie in Powershell to make it work proprely

Comment: you can use `@(Get-PSDrive -PSProvider FileSystem).Where({$_.DisplayRoot -notmatch '^\\'})` to get a list of drive letters on a system. then you can iterate thru that list do do your next steps. [*grin*]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well thanks for your help, I just manage to make it works like that :

```
$lecteur=[int][char]'A'

1..26 | % {
    $LR=[char]$lecteur
    $contenu =[System.IO.File]::ReadAllText("$path\$SharedFolders.txt").Replace("${LR}:\","\\$SharedFolders\$LR$\")
    [System.IO.File]::WriteAllText("$path\$SharedFolders.txt", $contenu)
    $lecteur++
}
```

Hope it'll help some people ;)

Answer (score 0):

- You need PSv6 to use `'a'..'z'`
- The `-replace` operator is RegEx based, you need to escape a literal backslash with another one in the pattern.
- following [@Lee_Dailey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3080908/lee-dailey)s hint build a RegEx with valid Drive letters

---

```
$OFS = '|'
$RE  = ('('+(Get-Psdrive -PSProvider filesystem).where({$_.Displayroot -notmatch '^\\'}).name)+'):\\'
$OFS = $Null

"`$RE = '{0}'" -f $RE

'Loop to replace c:\, d:\ … z:\ with \\servername\c$\' -replace $RE,"\\servername\`${1}$\"
```

Sample output on my PC

```
$RE = '(A|C|D):\\'
Loop to replace \\servername\c$\, \\servername\d$\ … z:\ with \\servername\c$\
```

Reading the file with the -raw parameter doesn't require a loop, but wil do all changes at once.

```
$OFS = '|'
$RE  = ('('+(Get-Psdrive -PSProvider filesystem).where({$_.Displayroot -notmatch '^\\'}).name)+'):\\'
$OFS = $Null

$File = "$path\$SharedFolders.txt"
(Get-Content $File -raw) -replace $RE,"\\servername\`${1}$\" |
 Set-Content $File
```